# TreeBuilder in Symfony2 config validation arrays

Tags: php, symfony

I do understand how to config validation works in symfony2 (treeBuilder) but I cannot validate at least one array with two values

```
mike_test:
    param: 
        - [123, 20]
        - [234, 40]
```

So I start with this:

```
$treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
$rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('mike_test');
$rootNode
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('param')

        ->end()
    ->end();
```

And I get a message "Unrecognized options "0, 1" under "mike_test.param"
Can someone help

Comment: I don't have experience with the treebuilder, but take a look at the prototype feature: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html#array-nodes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is still possible, 
you must define the type or category of data in your array

```
->arrayNode('param')
     ->isRequired()
     ->prototype('scalar')->end()
->end()
```